# Java JSON Decoder

Tags: java, json

I'm getting an error code(below) and I can't decode the string, I know it is finding the JSON and the file I saved it too, but it not parsing.
Error Code:

```
Unexpected token VALUE(-10) at position 83.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:257)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    at Employee.retrieveData(Employee.java:103)
    at EmployeeTest.main(EmployeeTest.java:9)
```

Code:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String s = null;
        try {

        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Error: No Data");
            return;
        }

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        s=br.readLine();
        fr.close();
        br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
//s = {"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Hope","isEmployeeClockedIn":false,"clockedOut":2015-10-06 23:51:10.751,"id":0,"clockedIn":2015-10-06 23:51:10.751}
            Object obj = parser.parse(s);
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
            System.out.println(obj);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: So... where is the JSON that failed to parse? You might want to edit your question to include that.

Comment: JSOn starts with `{` is not a `JSONArray` its a `JSONObject`

Comment: I tried that, gave me sane error code, maybe by chance I didn't run the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid JSON:

```
{"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Hope","isEmployeeClockedIn":false,"clockedOut":2015-10-06 23:51:10.751,"id":0,"clockedIn":2015-10-06 23:51:10.751}
```

The parse is failing at "clockedOut":2015 **-10** -06.

The value should be quoted:

```
"clockedOut":"2015-10-06 23:51:10.751"
```

Comment: I thought it wasn't like that since I ran it to a JSON.. Alright, I'll double check that tomorrow. Thanks!